# Print all 3 by 3 sturdy squares

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, number-theory, grid

A sturdy square (akin to a [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)) is an arrangement of the integers 1 to \$N^2\$ on an \$N\$ by \$N\$ grid such that every 2 by 2 subgrid has the same sum.

For example, for \$N = 3\$ one sturdy square is

```
1 5 3
9 8 7
4 2 6
```

because the four 2 by 2 subgrids

```
1 5
9 8
```

```
5 3
8 7
```

```
9 8
4 2
```

```
8 7
2 6
```

all sum to the same amount, 23:

$$23 = 1 + 5 + 9 + 8 = 5 + 3 + 8 + 7 = 9 + 8 + 4 + 2 = 8 + 7 + 2 + 6$$

Now there are sturdy squares for higher values of N and even rectangular versions but your only task in this challenge is to output all possible 3 by 3 sturdy squares. There are exactly 376 distinct 3 by 3 sturdy squares, including those that are reflections or rotations of others, and not all of them have the same sum of 23.

Write a program or function that takes no input but prints or returns a string of all 376 sturdy squares in any order, separated by empty lines, with up to two optional trailing newlines. Each square should consist of three lines of three space separated nonzero decimal digits.

Here is a valid output example:

```
1 5 3
9 8 7
4 2 6

1 5 6
8 7 3
4 2 9

1 5 6
8 9 3
2 4 7

1 5 7
9 6 3
2 4 8

1 6 2
8 9 7
4 3 5

1 6 2
9 7 8
4 3 5

1 6 3
9 8 7
2 5 4

1 6 7
8 5 2
3 4 9

1 6 7
9 4 3
2 5 8

1 7 2
9 4 8
5 3 6

1 7 2
9 6 8
3 5 4

1 7 4
8 3 5
6 2 9

1 7 4
9 2 6
5 3 8

1 7 6
9 2 4
3 5 8

1 8 2
5 9 4
6 3 7

1 8 3
6 5 4
7 2 9

1 8 3
9 2 7
4 5 6

1 8 4
5 7 2
6 3 9

1 8 4
6 9 3
2 7 5

1 8 4
9 3 6
2 7 5

1 8 6
7 3 2
4 5 9

1 9 2
5 6 4
7 3 8

1 9 2
6 4 5
7 3 8

1 9 2
6 8 5
3 7 4

1 9 2
8 3 7
4 6 5

1 9 3
7 2 5
6 4 8

1 9 3
7 6 5
2 8 4

1 9 4
5 8 2
3 7 6

1 9 4
6 7 3
2 8 5

1 9 4
8 2 5
3 7 6

1 9 5
7 2 3
4 6 8

1 9 5
7 4 3
2 8 6

2 3 5
9 8 6
4 1 7

2 3 6
9 7 5
4 1 8

2 4 3
8 9 7
5 1 6

2 4 3
9 7 8
5 1 6

2 4 6
7 8 3
5 1 9

2 4 7
8 9 3
1 5 6

2 4 8
9 6 3
1 5 7

2 5 3
9 4 8
6 1 7

2 5 4
9 3 7
6 1 8

2 5 4
9 8 7
1 6 3

2 5 7
6 8 1
4 3 9

2 5 7
6 9 1
3 4 8

2 5 8
7 6 1
3 4 9

2 5 8
9 4 3
1 6 7

2 6 1
7 9 8
5 3 4

2 6 1
8 7 9
5 3 4

2 6 3
5 9 4
7 1 8

2 6 4
5 8 3
7 1 9

2 6 7
9 1 4
3 5 8

2 6 8
7 4 1
3 5 9

2 7 1
8 4 9
6 3 5

2 7 1
8 6 9
4 5 3

2 7 3
5 6 4
8 1 9

2 7 3
6 4 5
8 1 9

2 7 3
9 1 8
5 4 6

2 7 5
4 8 1
6 3 9

2 7 5
6 9 3
1 8 4

2 7 5
9 3 6
1 8 4

2 8 1
4 9 5
7 3 6

2 8 4
7 6 5
1 9 3

2 8 5
4 9 1
3 7 6

2 8 5
6 7 3
1 9 4

2 8 6
7 4 3
1 9 5

2 9 1
4 6 5
8 3 7

2 9 1
5 4 6
8 3 7

2 9 1
5 8 6
4 7 3

2 9 1
7 3 8
5 6 4

2 9 3
6 1 5
7 4 8

2 9 4
3 7 1
6 5 8

2 9 4
3 8 1
5 6 7

2 9 5
4 7 1
3 8 6

2 9 5
7 1 4
3 8 6

2 9 6
5 3 1
4 7 8

2 9 6
5 4 1
3 8 7

3 2 5
9 8 7
4 1 6

3 2 6
8 9 5
4 1 7

3 2 7
9 6 5
4 1 8

3 4 2
7 9 8
6 1 5

3 4 2
8 7 9
6 1 5

3 4 5
9 2 7
6 1 8

3 4 8
6 9 1
2 5 7

3 4 9
7 6 1
2 5 8

3 4 9
8 5 2
1 6 7

3 5 1
7 8 9
6 2 4

3 5 2
8 4 9
7 1 6

3 5 4
9 1 8
6 2 7

3 5 4
9 6 8
1 7 2

3 5 8
9 1 4
2 6 7

3 5 8
9 2 4
1 7 6

3 5 9
7 4 1
2 6 8

3 6 1
7 8 9
4 5 2

3 6 2
4 9 5
8 1 7

3 6 8
7 1 2
4 5 9

3 7 2
4 6 5
9 1 8

3 7 2
5 4 6
9 1 8

3 7 2
8 1 9
6 4 5

3 7 4
6 1 5
8 2 9

3 7 4
6 8 5
1 9 2

3 7 6
4 9 1
2 8 5

3 7 6
5 8 2
1 9 4

3 7 6
8 2 5
1 9 4

3 8 1
4 5 6
9 2 7

3 8 1
7 2 9
6 5 4

3 8 4
2 9 1
6 5 7

3 8 6
4 7 1
2 9 5

3 8 6
7 1 4
2 9 5

3 8 7
5 4 1
2 9 6

3 9 1
5 2 7
8 4 6

3 9 1
5 6 7
4 8 2

3 9 2
5 1 6
8 4 7

3 9 4
2 6 1
7 5 8

3 9 4
2 8 1
5 7 6

3 9 6
4 2 1
5 7 8

3 9 6
5 1 2
4 8 7

4 1 6
9 8 7
3 2 5

4 1 7
8 9 5
3 2 6

4 1 7
9 8 6
2 3 5

4 1 8
9 6 5
3 2 7

4 1 8
9 7 5
2 3 6

4 2 6
9 8 7
1 5 3

4 2 7
6 9 3
5 1 8

4 2 7
9 3 6
5 1 8

4 2 8
7 6 3
5 1 9

4 2 9
8 7 3
1 5 6

4 3 5
8 9 7
1 6 2

4 3 5
9 2 8
6 1 7

4 3 5
9 7 8
1 6 2

4 3 7
5 8 2
6 1 9

4 3 7
8 2 5
6 1 9

4 3 7
9 1 6
5 2 8

4 3 9
6 8 1
2 5 7

4 5 2
7 3 9
8 1 6

4 5 2
7 8 9
3 6 1

4 5 3
8 1 9
7 2 6

4 5 3
8 6 9
2 7 1

4 5 6
3 8 1
7 2 9

4 5 6
9 2 7
1 8 3

4 5 9
7 1 2
3 6 8

4 5 9
7 3 2
1 8 6

4 6 2
3 8 5
9 1 7

4 6 5
2 9 1
7 3 8

4 6 5
8 3 7
1 9 2

4 6 8
7 2 3
1 9 5

4 7 1
5 3 8
9 2 6

4 7 1
6 2 9
8 3 5

4 7 3
5 1 6
9 2 8

4 7 3
5 8 6
2 9 1

4 7 5
2 6 1
8 3 9

4 7 8
5 3 1
2 9 6

4 8 1
2 7 5
9 3 6

4 8 1
3 9 6
5 7 2

4 8 1
6 3 9
5 7 2

4 8 2
5 6 7
3 9 1

4 8 3
1 9 2
7 5 6

4 8 6
3 2 1
7 5 9

4 8 7
5 1 2
3 9 6

4 9 1
2 8 5
6 7 3

4 9 1
3 7 6
5 8 2

4 9 1
5 2 8
6 7 3

4 9 2
1 7 3
8 5 6

4 9 2
1 8 3
7 6 5

4 9 3
1 6 2
8 5 7

4 9 3
1 8 2
6 7 5

4 9 5
2 3 1
7 6 8

4 9 5
3 1 2
7 6 8

4 9 6
3 2 1
5 8 7

5 1 6
8 9 7
2 4 3

5 1 6
9 7 8
2 4 3

5 1 8
6 9 3
4 2 7

5 1 8
9 3 6
4 2 7

5 1 9
7 6 3
4 2 8

5 1 9
7 8 3
2 4 6

5 2 3
7 8 9
6 1 4

5 2 8
7 3 4
6 1 9

5 2 8
9 1 6
4 3 7

5 3 2
6 8 9
7 1 4

5 3 4
7 9 8
2 6 1

5 3 4
8 2 9
7 1 6

5 3 4
8 7 9
2 6 1

5 3 6
9 4 8
1 7 2

5 3 8
4 7 1
6 2 9

5 3 8
7 1 4
6 2 9

5 3 8
9 2 6
1 7 4

5 4 3
7 2 9
8 1 6

5 4 6
3 7 2
8 1 9

5 4 6
9 1 8
2 7 3

5 6 4
1 9 2
8 3 7

5 6 4
7 3 8
2 9 1

5 6 7
3 8 1
2 9 4

5 7 2
1 8 4
9 3 6

5 7 2
3 9 6
4 8 1

5 7 2
6 3 9
4 8 1

5 7 4
1 6 2
9 3 8

5 7 6
2 3 1
8 4 9

5 7 6
2 8 1
3 9 4

5 7 6
3 1 2
8 4 9

5 7 8
4 2 1
3 9 6

5 8 2
1 9 4
6 7 3

5 8 2
3 7 6
4 9 1

5 8 7
3 2 1
4 9 6

5 9 1
3 2 7
8 6 4

5 9 1
3 4 7
6 8 2

5 9 2
1 7 4
6 8 3

5 9 2
4 1 7
6 8 3

5 9 4
1 3 2
8 6 7

5 9 4
2 1 3
8 6 7

6 1 4
7 8 9
5 2 3

6 1 5
7 9 8
3 4 2

6 1 5
8 7 9
3 4 2

6 1 7
9 2 8
4 3 5

6 1 7
9 4 8
2 5 3

6 1 8
9 2 7
3 4 5

6 1 8
9 3 7
2 5 4

6 1 9
5 8 2
4 3 7

6 1 9
7 3 4
5 2 8

6 1 9
8 2 5
4 3 7

6 2 3
5 9 8
7 1 4

6 2 4
7 8 9
3 5 1

6 2 7
9 1 8
3 5 4

6 2 8
5 4 3
7 1 9

6 2 9
4 7 1
5 3 8

6 2 9
7 1 4
5 3 8

6 2 9
8 3 5
1 7 4

6 3 2
5 7 9
8 1 4

6 3 5
8 4 9
2 7 1

6 3 7
5 2 4
8 1 9

6 3 7
5 9 4
1 8 2

6 3 9
4 8 1
2 7 5

6 3 9
5 7 2
1 8 4

6 4 2
3 8 7
9 1 5

6 4 5
2 7 3
9 1 8

6 4 5
8 1 9
3 7 2

6 4 8
7 2 5
1 9 3

6 5 1
3 7 8
9 2 4

6 5 1
3 9 8
7 4 2

6 5 4
1 8 3
9 2 7

6 5 4
7 2 9
3 8 1

6 5 7
2 4 1
8 3 9

6 5 7
2 9 1
3 8 4

6 5 8
3 2 1
7 4 9

6 5 8
3 7 1
2 9 4

6 7 1
4 2 9
8 5 3

6 7 3
1 9 4
5 8 2

6 7 3
2 8 5
4 9 1

6 7 3
5 2 8
4 9 1

6 7 5
1 3 2
9 4 8

6 7 5
1 8 2
4 9 3

6 7 5
2 1 3
9 4 8

6 8 1
2 3 7
9 5 4

6 8 2
3 4 7
5 9 1

6 8 3
1 7 4
5 9 2

6 8 3
4 1 7
5 9 2

6 8 4
1 2 3
9 5 7

6 9 2
1 3 5
8 7 4

6 9 2
1 4 5
7 8 3

6 9 3
1 2 4
8 7 5

6 9 3
2 1 5
7 8 4

6 9 4
1 2 3
7 8 5

7 1 4
5 9 8
6 2 3

7 1 4
6 8 9
5 3 2

7 1 6
8 2 9
5 3 4

7 1 6
8 4 9
3 5 2

7 1 8
5 9 4
2 6 3

7 1 9
5 4 3
6 2 8

7 1 9
5 8 3
2 6 4

7 2 3
5 6 9
8 1 4

7 2 4
3 9 6
8 1 5

7 2 4
6 3 9
8 1 5

7 2 6
8 1 9
4 5 3

7 2 9
3 8 1
4 5 6

7 2 9
6 5 4
1 8 3

7 3 4
2 8 5
9 1 6

7 3 4
5 2 8
9 1 6

7 3 4
6 1 9
8 2 5

7 3 6
4 2 5
9 1 8

7 3 6
4 9 5
2 8 1

7 3 8
2 9 1
4 6 5

7 3 8
5 6 4
1 9 2

7 3 8
6 4 5
1 9 2

7 4 2
3 9 8
6 5 1

7 4 8
6 1 5
2 9 3

7 4 9
3 2 1
6 5 8

7 5 1
3 6 9
8 4 2

7 5 2
1 8 6
9 3 4

7 5 2
1 9 6
8 4 3

7 5 6
1 4 2
9 3 8

7 5 6
1 9 2
4 8 3

7 5 8
2 6 1
3 9 4

7 5 9
3 2 1
4 8 6

7 6 1
2 5 8
9 4 3

7 6 1
3 4 9
8 5 2

7 6 2
4 1 9
8 5 3

7 6 5
1 8 3
4 9 2

7 6 8
2 3 1
4 9 5

7 6 8
3 1 2
4 9 5

7 8 3
1 4 5
6 9 2

7 8 4
2 1 5
6 9 3

7 8 5
1 2 3
6 9 4

8 1 4
5 6 9
7 2 3

8 1 4
5 7 9
6 3 2

8 1 5
3 9 6
7 2 4

8 1 5
6 3 9
7 2 4

8 1 6
7 2 9
5 4 3

8 1 6
7 3 9
4 5 2

8 1 7
4 9 5
3 6 2

8 1 9
3 7 2
5 4 6

8 1 9
5 2 4
6 3 7

8 1 9
5 6 4
2 7 3

8 1 9
6 4 5
2 7 3

8 2 4
3 6 7
9 1 5

8 2 5
4 3 7
9 1 6

8 2 5
6 1 9
7 3 4

8 2 6
3 4 5
9 1 7

8 2 9
6 1 5
3 7 4

8 3 5
1 7 4
9 2 6

8 3 5
4 1 7
9 2 6

8 3 5
6 2 9
4 7 1

8 3 7
1 9 2
5 6 4

8 3 7
4 6 5
2 9 1

8 3 7
5 4 6
2 9 1

8 3 9
2 4 1
6 5 7

8 3 9
2 6 1
4 7 5

8 4 2
3 6 9
7 5 1

8 4 3
1 9 6
7 5 2

8 4 6
5 2 7
3 9 1

8 4 7
5 1 6
3 9 2

8 4 9
2 3 1
5 7 6

8 4 9
3 1 2
5 7 6

8 5 2
1 6 7
9 4 3

8 5 2
3 4 9
7 6 1

8 5 3
4 1 9
7 6 2

8 5 3
4 2 9
6 7 1

8 5 6
1 2 3
9 4 7

8 5 6
1 7 3
4 9 2

8 5 7
1 6 2
4 9 3

8 6 2
1 4 7
9 5 3

8 6 3
2 1 7
9 5 4

8 6 4
3 2 7
5 9 1

8 6 7
1 3 2
5 9 4

8 6 7
2 1 3
5 9 4

8 7 4
1 3 5
6 9 2

8 7 5
1 2 4
6 9 3

9 1 5
3 6 7
8 2 4

9 1 5
3 8 7
6 4 2

9 1 6
2 8 5
7 3 4

9 1 6
4 3 7
8 2 5

9 1 6
5 2 8
7 3 4

9 1 7
3 4 5
8 2 6

9 1 7
3 8 5
4 6 2

9 1 8
2 7 3
6 4 5

9 1 8
4 2 5
7 3 6

9 1 8
4 6 5
3 7 2

9 1 8
5 4 6
3 7 2

9 2 4
3 7 8
6 5 1

9 2 6
1 7 4
8 3 5

9 2 6
4 1 7
8 3 5

9 2 6
5 3 8
4 7 1

9 2 7
1 8 3
6 5 4

9 2 7
4 5 6
3 8 1

9 2 8
5 1 6
4 7 3

9 3 4
1 8 6
7 5 2

9 3 6
1 8 4
5 7 2

9 3 6
2 7 5
4 8 1

9 3 8
1 4 2
7 5 6

9 3 8
1 6 2
5 7 4

9 4 3
1 6 7
8 5 2

9 4 3
2 5 8
7 6 1

9 4 7
1 2 3
8 5 6

9 4 8
1 3 2
6 7 5

9 4 8
2 1 3
6 7 5

9 5 3
1 4 7
8 6 2

9 5 4
2 1 7
8 6 3

9 5 4
2 3 7
6 8 1

9 5 7
1 2 3
6 8 4
```

Your program must produce these same 376 sturdy squares, just not necessarily in this order. The output does not need to be deterministic, i.e. you could output them in different orders on different runs as long as they are all there.

**The shortest code in bytes wins.**

<sup>The topic of sturdy squares originated with [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24810050#24810050) of mine which led to a large amount of discussion on their properties and how to generate them. Props to [Peter Taylor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/5294), [feersum](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/127072), and [Sp3000](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/17335/sp3000) for continuing the discussion, and especially to [El'endia Starman](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/14404) for [drafting](https://oeis.org/draft/A263542) a corresponding [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A263542).</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure if I interpreted the *trailing newline* rule correctly. The output of my previous revision ended with `5 7 3\n\n`, so there is one blank line after the last square. Is that admissible?

Comment: Yayyy I get extra props! :P

Comment: Maybe host the output somewhere else so that it is not too long on this page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>38</s> <s>34</s> <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```
Vfq2l{sMX2.DR2.:T5b.pS9Vc3NjdH)k
```

*5 bytes saved in formatting by Jakube*

*1 byte saved by switching to Peter Taylor's substrings of length five, remove the middles approach*

Takes about a minute and a half to run on my machine.

How it works at the high level:

- Generate all permutations (`.pS9`)
- Form length 5 substrings (`.:T5`)
- Remove the center element of each (`.DR2`)
- Append a newline to the center element, marking it with a necessarily different sum (`X2 ... b`)
- Filter for the squares where all such sums are equal (`fq2l{`)
- Format and print (`V ... Vc3NjdH)k`)

Comment: Chop `N` inside the loop (`V...Vc3N`) instead of before the loop (`VcL3...VN`). Saves one additional byte.

Answer (score 10):

### Python 3, <s>169</s> <s>168</s> 164 bytes

Took the program I used to investigate these sturdy squares/rectangles and golfed it wayyyy down. Golfed off 4 bytes thanks to otakucode.

```py
from itertools import*
r=range(1,10)
for p in permutations(r,6):
 x,y=p[0],p[5];q=p[:5]+(x+p[3]-p[2],y,y+p[1]-x,p[2]+y-x)
 if set(q)==set(r):print('%s %s %s\n'*3%q)
```

#### Explanation

Given a partially-filled sturdy square like this,

```py
a b c
d e ?
g ? ?
```

The remaining three entries are uniquely determined, and are `a+d-c`, `a+b-g`, and `c+g-a`. So I generate all permutations of 0..8 with six elements, calculate the rest, and then check to see whether the set of this is the same as the set of 0..8. If it is, I print out the grid.

---

For reference, here's the original (with comments and extraneous code removed):

```py
from itertools import permutations as P

n = 3
m = 3
permutes = P(range(m*n), m+n)

counter = 0
for p in permutes:
    grid = [p[:n]]
    for i in range(m-1):
        grid.append([p[n+i]]+[-1]*(n-1))
    grid[1][1] = p[-1]

    s = p[0]+p[1]+p[n]+p[-1]

    has = list(p)

    fail = 0
    for y in range(1,m):
        for x in range(1,n):
            if x == y == 1: continue

            r = s-(grid[y-1][x-1] + grid[y-1][x] + grid[y][x-1])

            if r not in has and 0 <= r < m*n:
                grid[y][x] = r
                has.append(r)
            else:
                fail = 1
                break

        if fail: break

    if not fail:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Comment: love this technique

Comment: Very nice approach!  You can still save a few bytes though... in the loop, x,y=p[0],p[5]  then q=p+(y+p[3]-p[2],y+p[1]-x,p[2]+x-y)

Comment: @otakucode: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8):

## CJam, <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
A,1>e!3f/{2{2few:::+z}*:|,1=},Ma*Sf*N*
```

*Thanks to @PeterTaylor for golfing off 2 bytes!*

This finishes instantly using the Java interpreter. It works using the online interpreter as well, but it requires a little patience. [Try it online.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=A%2C1%3Ee!3f%2F%7B2%7B2few%3A%3A%3A%2Bz%7D*%3A%7C%2C1%3D%7D%2CMa*Sf*N*)

#### Test run

```
$ cjam sturdy-squares.cjam | head -n 8
1 5 3
9 8 7
4 2 6

1 5 6
8 7 3
4 2 9

$ cjam sturdy-squares.cjam | tail -n 8

9 5 4
2 3 7
6 8 1

9 5 7
1 2 3
6 8 4
$
```

#### How it works

```
A,1>     e# Push [1 ... 9].
e!       e# Push the array of all permutations of that array.
3f/      e# Split each into rows of length 3.
{        e# Filter; push the permutation, then:
  2{     e#   Do the following twice:
    2few e#     Split each row into overlapping splices of length 2.
         e#       [a b c] -> [[a b] [b c]]
    :::+ e#     Reduce each innermost vector to its sum.
         e#       [[a b] [b c]] -> [a+b b+c]
    z    e#     Transpose rows with columns.
  }*     e#   The result is [[s t] [u v]], the sums of all 2x2 squares.
  :|     e#   Perform set union of the pairs of sums.
  ,1=    e#   Check if the length of the result is 1 (unique sum).
},       e# Keep the array if the result was 1.
{        e# For each kept array:
  Sf*    e#   Join the elements of its rows, separating by spaces.
  ~M     e#   Dump the resulting strings and an empty string on the stack.
}%       e# Collect everything in an array.
N*       e# Join the strings, separating by linefeeds.
```

Comment: +1 And I was happy with the brevity of my answer!

Comment: Now that I've managed to golf my answer enough to stay one char ahead: `Ma*Sf*N*` saves two over `{Sf*~M}%N*`

Comment: @PeterTaylor It does indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3.5, 135 bytes

```py
from itertools import*
for x in permutations(range(1,10)):eval((("=="+"+x[%s]"*3)*4)[2:]%(*"013125367578",))and print("%d %d %d\n"*3%x)
```

Directly checks the sum of each square, minus the middle. Most likely still golfable by the "`itertools` is unnecessary" rule-of-thumb.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <s>147 166 155</s> 149 bytes

This generates the permutations of {1,2,3...9} and selects cases for which

(sum of digits at positions {1,2,4,5}) =

(sum of digits at positions {2,3,5,6}) =

(sum of the digits at positions {4,5,7,8}) =

(sum of the digits at positions {5,6,8,9})

```
f@s_:=Length@Tally[Tr@Extract[s,#]&/@Table[{{0},{1},{3},{4}}+k,{k,{1,2,4,5}}]]>1;
Row[Grid/@(#~Partition~3&/@Select[Permutations@Range@9,f@#&]),"\n"]
```

**Output** (a partial look)

[image: output]

---

```
Length[%]
```

> 376

Answer (score 5):

### CJam (<strike>39</strike> 37 bytes)

```
A,1>e!{5ew{2Mtz}2*::+)-!},3f/Ma*Sf*N*
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=A%2C1%3Ee!%7B5ew%7B2Mtz%7D2*%3A%3A%2B)-!%7D%2C3f%2FMa*Sf*N*) (warning: may take over a minute to run, triggering "Abort this script?" prompts from the browser).

Works by filtering all possible grids using `5ew` to map

```
[a b c d e f g h i]
```

to

```
[[a b c d e]
 [b c d e f]
 [c d e f g]
 [d e f g h]
 [e f g h i]]
```

and then discarding the middle element and the middle element of each other element to get

```
[[a b d e]
 [b c e f]
 [d e g h]
 [e f h i]]
```

which are the four squares.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

## Python2 <del>327</del> <del>271</del> <del>270</del> <del>263</del> 260 bytes

```
z,v,s={},3,range(1,10)
while len(z)<376:
 for i in range(8):v=hash(`v`);s[i],s[v%9]=s[v%9],s[i]
 m=map(lambda i:sum(s[i:i+5])-s[i+2],[0,1,3,4]);T=tuple(s)
 if all(x==m[0] for x in m) and not T in z:
  z[T]=1;print '%i %i %i\n'*3 % tuple(s[0:3]+s[3:6]+s[6:9])
```

### ------------

This is... not so short but it uses no libraries. This randomly permutes a square, checks it for magicness, prints it, and records it to prevent duplicates. After it has printed 376 unique magic squares, it stops.

I borrowed the Pseudo Random Number Generator from Keith Randall's entry for the golf named " [Build a random number generator that passes the Diehard tests](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10553/build-a-random-number-generator-that-passes-the-diehard-tests) "

```
z,v={},3
def R(x,y):global v;v=hash(`v`);return v
while len(z)<376:
 s=sorted(range(1,10),cmp=R)
 m=[sum(q) for q in map(lambda p:s[p[0]:p[1]+1]+s[p[2]:p[3]+1], [[i,i+1,i+3,i+4] for i in [0,1,3,4]] )]
 if all(x==m[0] for x in m) and not tuple(s) in z.keys():
  z[tuple(s)]=1;print '%i %i %i\n'*3 % tuple(s[0:3]+s[3:6]+s[6:9])
```

De-golfed

```
# each magic square is an array of 9 numbers
#
#for example [1 9 3 7 2 5 6 4 8] 
#
#represents the following square
#
#1 9 3
#7 2 5
#6 4 8
#
# to generate a random square with each number represented only once,
# start with [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] and sort, but use a random comparison
# function so the sorting process becomes instead a random permutation.
# 
# to check each 2x2 subsquare for sums, look at the indexes into the
# array: [[0,1,3,4] = upper left,[1,2,4,5] = upper right, etc.
#
# to keep track of already-printed magic squares, use a dictionary    
# (associative array) where the 9-element array data is the key. 

from random import *
def magic(s):
 quads=[]
 for a,b,c,d in [[0,1,3,4],[1,2,4,5],[3,4,6,7],[4,5,7,8]]:
  quads+=[s[a:b+1]+s[c:d+1]]
 summ=[sum(q) for q in quads]
 same= all(x==summ[0] for x in summ)
 #print quads
 #print 'sum',summ
 #print 'same',same
 return same

magicsquares={}
while len(magicsquares.keys())<376:
        sq = sorted(range(1,10),key=lambda x:random())
        if magic(sq) and not magicsquares.has_key(tuple(sq)):
                magicsquares[tuple(sq)]=1
                print sq[0:3],'\n',sq[3:6],'\n',sq[6:9],'\n'
```

Comment: Nothing random needs to be happening. There are exactly 376 distinct square solutions and you need to output each of them exactly once.

Comment: i did print exactly 376 distinct square solutions, and i output each of them exactly once. randomness is not banned in the description, nor is it banned in the 'standard loopholes' http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default

Comment: Alright, fair enough.

Comment: You can use a worse random number generator as long as it gives you all of the squares you need.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 133

```rb
a=[]
[*1..9].permutation{|x|[0,1,3,4].map{|i|x[i]+x[i+1]+x[i+3]+x[i+4]}.uniq.size<2&&a<<x.each_slice(3).map{|s|s*' '}*'
'}
$><<a*'

'
```

Straightforward brute force approach. Test it [here](http://ideone.com/mO09Mj).

Answer (score 1):

## J, 83 bytes

```
([:;@,(<LF),.~[:(<@(LF,~":)"1@#~([:*/2=/\[:,2 2+/@,;._3])"2)(3 3)($"1)1+!A.&i.])@9:
```

This is a function that outputs a string containing the 376 sturdy squares. Uses brute-force, generates all permutations of 1 thru 9, shape each into a 3x3 array, and filters it by checking if the sums of each 2x2 subarray are equal. Completes in half a second.

### Usage

```
   f =: ([:;@,(<LF),.~[:(<@(LF,~":)"1@#~([:*/2=/\[:,2 2+/@,;._3])"2)(3 3)($"1)1+!A.&i.])@9:
   $ f ''  NB. A function has to take something to be invoked,
           NB. but in this case it is not used by the function
   37 {. f ''  NB. Take the first 37 characters
1 5 3
9 8 7
4 2 6

1 5 6
8 7 3
4 2 9

   _38 {. f ''  NB. Take the last 38 characters
9 5 4
2 3 7
6 8 1

9 5 7
1 2 3
6 8 4


   NB. The output string ends with two newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 38 bytes

```apl
s⌿⍨1=≢∘∪⍤1⍪+/,⍤⊢⌺1 2 2⊢s←3 3⍴⍤1⌂pmat 9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97X/xo579j3pXGNo@6lz0qGPGo45Vj3qXGD7qXaWtrwNkPepa9Khnl6GCkYIRkFn8qG2CsYLxo94tYEU9TQW5iSUKliCT/qdxAQA)

Uses the builtin `dfns.pmat` to generate required permutations.

Will add an explanation soon.

Made with golfing help from Adám, who also ran the program on his machine for checking. ↓

[image]

### Explanation

```apl
s⌿⍨1=≢∘∪⍤1⍪+/,⍤⊢⌺1 2 2⊢s←3 3⍴⍤1⌂pmat 9
                             1⌂pmat 9 matrix of permutations of 1..9
                      s←3 3⍴⍤         convert each to 3x3 matrix, and store in s
              ⊢⌺1 2 2⊢                get all overlapping 2x2 squares in each of those   
        1⍪+/,⍤                        sum the flattened 2x2's of each
  1=≢∘∪⍤                              is there only 1 unique sum?
                                      this creates a bitmask for filtering each 3x3
s⌿⍨                                   filter s by that
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
9Œ!s€3+Ɲ€Z$⁺FEƲƇG€j⁾¶¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/y6CTF4kdNa4y1j80FUlEqjxp3ubke23Ss3R3IzXrUuO/QtkPb/v8HAA)

*Very* inefficient. Times out on TIO, and takes around 4m30s on my local computer. Uses [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61437/66833)' method for finding the sums of the 2x2 submatrices. The last 6 bytes could be removed if the output format was more permissive. Outputs in the same order as in the question.

### How it works

```
9Œ!s€3+Ɲ€Z$⁺FEƲƇG€j⁾¶¶ - Main link. No arguments
9Œ!                    - Yield all permutations of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
   s€3                 - Split each into a 3x3 matrix
              ƲƇ       - Keep those for which the following is true:
       Ɲ€              -   Over each neighbouring pair in each row:
      +                -     Take the sum
         Z             -    Transpose
          $⁺           -    Do this again
            F          -    Flatten
             E         -    Are all elements equal?
                G€     - Join each row by spaces and then join rows by newlines
                  j⁾¶¶ - Join the final matrices with two newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 34 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

+9 bytes for the output formatting :\

```
9õ á mò3 kÈ®ä+ÃÕ®ä+Ãrâ ÊÉÃ®m¸·ÃqR²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=OfUg4SBt8jMga8iu5CvD1a7kK8Ny4iDKycOubbi3w3FSsg&input=IjEgNSAzCjkgOCA3CjQgMiA2Ig)